# Transactions without signatures?

Tags: transactions, signature, input-script

Do all transactions require a siganture to be broadcasted and signed or is it possible to have a unsigned transaction be mined?

Could you not just use op codes to allow a transaction to be validated without a signature?

Such as making the scriptsig OP_true?

Answer (score 2):

Transactions do not require a signature to be valid. Signatures are just a way of ensuring that the transaction is not going to be spent by anyone, but just by the person who holds the correct private key and therefore, is able to perform a valid signature.

Here you have an example of a transaction spent without signature. [tx1](https://blockstream.info/testnet/nojs/tx/da58f6688b0727a7f1bf3eec899099bde1f18b9c7099f9d2c79556db238e623d?expand) is a transaction spending from a P2PKH address and creating a P2SH output that requires an `OP_TRUE` to be spent. [tx2](https://blockstream.info/testnet/nojs/tx/839b903b9f79c3372792ceb95917047c46d1b919ed1f6471f5a19d7c865ab32c?expand) is a transaction spending from `tx1` by just providing that `OP_TRUE (51)`

Answer (score 1):

> Do all transactions require a siganture to be broadcasted

No. Bitcoin does not require that valid transaction must have signature verification.

Comment: So why would you get an error like script not push only if you try to broadcast a unsigned transaction?

Comment: The fact is: some transactions do not contain signatures and still valid. This does not mean that arbitrary transaction without signature is valid

Comment: Could you give me an example of a transaction like that which has been mined?

Comment: https://blockchain.info/tx/fdce158d8d9ef51b3fc53d7569f5448ffaa8a28be25992fbb060a36a4715a34c?show_adv=true